# PHP: error echoing a bidimentional array -> Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have the following bidimentional array called: available_years_with_months:

```
Array
(
    [2017] => Array
        (
            [0] => January
        )

    [2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => December
            [59] => November
            [148] => October
            [149] => September
            [167] => August
            [534] => April
        )

    [2014] => Array
        (
            [0] => August
        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => August
        )
)
```

and I want to echo it inside a  html in this way: January 2017, December 2016, November 2016, etc... as shown in the picture:

[image]

I wrote this select statement in HTML to pull the month and the year:

```
<select>
  <option value="all" selected>All dates</option>
  <?php foreach ($available_years_with_months as $month): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $month; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

But I got an error:

> ErrorException in b900386fd351eb78414201e8cfaa8c3c69c71170.php line 16: Array to string conversion

The line 16 is this one:

```
<option value="<?php echo $month; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$mont` is array of months, you need one more foreach

Comment: @bub I edited the answer with line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use nested loop here.

Loop 1 for years. Loop 2 for months.

```
<?php foreach ($available_years_with_months as $year => $months): ?>
    <?php foreach ($months as $month): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $month; ?> <?php echo $year; ?>">
           <?php echo $month; ?> <?php echo $year; ?>
       </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```